# How do you select a nested css element using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: html, css, selenium

For the following html code:

```
    <div class="r signbox">
    <form method="POST" id="loginByEmail">
        <dl>
            <dt>Seller Login</dt>
            <dd>
                <input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                <div class="error"></div>
```

How could I select the "email" attribute in name? The reason why is because the site uses two form boxes that have the same name so I want to target specifically the one in the class "r signbox". Thanks for your help, completely new to Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

First select all the content of the class "r signbox" in your selector.

After you pick the desired information, you can take the derised information using a new selector in sequense in the same code block. As you asked, using attr name will be:

> $(".r.signbox [class='email']");

Answer (score 0):

By same name you mean the *id* attribute?

If so, that's odd.

If not, I suggest you to map first the *form* element and after the *input*. Doing so, you will be preventing your test to break in case another *form* to be added between the *div.r.signbox* and the *form.#loginByEmail*

Anyway, @Striter awnser is incorrect because he looking for anything with *email* as class.

A tip is to use the tags names to be more precise:

```
div.r.signbox input[name='email']
```

This looks for a div with both *r* and *signbox* and inside this element (see the space?) for an input with an attribute *name* valued as *email*.

Even if someone put a *div* with an attribute *name* valued as *email* between *dd* and *dt*, you locator will work fine.

Here is a good reference to CSS Selectors: https://saucelabs.com/selenium/css-selectors

If you like books, the first chapter of *Selenium Testing Tools Cookbook* will give you good knowledge: [http://www.amazon.com/Selenium-Testing-Cookbook-Gundecha-Unmesh/dp/1849515743](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849515743)